View text of Github Issue within VS Code
Is there a way to see the text of Github Issues in VS Code? The Github extension lists the issues, but to view the text you need to open a browser window:


Press F1, and type "Simple Browser: Show". This should open a browser tab in VS Code. Best you can do is copy the link, and paste it into the URL field.
